# Azure B2C Custom Policies - Pick IDP based on email

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've setup two Azure ADs (Domain01 / Domain02) configured them with my B2C (DomainB2C). I'm allowing these two domains to access API Management Developer portal as well as OpenID Connect Authroization.

Everything is working and I'm able to logon using accounts from the two different domains. I want to change one thing in this scenario, and It's when logging on. Right now,  there's a button for Domain01 and a button for Domain02. I'm trying to understand how to remove these buttons and instead just enter the email (user@domain01.onmicrosoft.com or user@domain02.onmicrosoft.com) and based upon the email choose the IDP - just like we do with Office 365 / Azure Portal.

I've followed the basic guides and I'm understanding more and more of how the custom policies work, I've tried domain hints and they work as well, but doesn't help since the app (API Management) don't know what domain_hint to send since the user haven't entered it's username.

Is this possible to do?

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported out of the box. You have two options:
1. You can wait for custom Javascript to be enabled. Vote for it [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15493536-add-support-for-javascript-inside-the-custom-ui-br). 
2. You can implement your own screen that takes username/password, and then depending on that, you can implement your own logic to call the right "domain_hint". You can also pass the username through using "login_hint"

Comment: I understand! I've voted for the javascript, will try my luck with my own screen. Thanks!